# preg_match_all and foreach only replacing last match

Tags: php, foreach, preg-match-all

I have the following code, which should make plain text links clickable. However, if there are several links, it only replaces the last one.

Code:

```
$nc = preg_match_all('#<pre[\s\S]*</pre>#U', $postbits, $matches_code); 
foreach($matches_code[0] AS $match_code) 
{
    $match = null;
    $matches = null;
    $url_regex = '#https?://(\w*:\w*@)?[-\w.]+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?[^<\.,:;"\'\s]+#'; 
    $n = preg_match_all($url_regex, $match_code, $matches);
    foreach($matches[0] AS $match)
    {
        $html_url = '<a href="' . $match . '" target="_blank">' . $match . '</a>';
        $match_string = str_replace($match, $html_url, $match_code);
    }
    $postbits = str_replace($match_code, $match_string, $postbits); 
}
```

Result:

```
http://www.google.com

http://www.yahoo.com

http://www.microsoft.com/ <-- only this one is clickable
```

Expected result:

> http://www.google.com
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/

Where is my error?

Comment: What's the point of `[\s\S]`? That matches everything, just like `.`. If the problem is that it doesn't match newlines use the `s` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

> if there are several links it only replaces the last one
>
> > Where is my error?

Actually, it's replacing all 3 links, but it replaces the original string each time.

```
foreach($matches[0] AS $match)
{
    $html_url = '<a href="' . $match . '" target="_blank">' . $match . '</a>';
    $match_string = str_replace($match, $html_url, $match_code);
}
```

The loop is executed 3 times, each time it replaces 1 link in `$match_code` and assigns the result to `$match_string`. On the first iteration, `$match_string` is assigned the result with a *clickable* `google.com`. On the second iteration, `$match_string` is assigned with a *clickable* `yahoo.com`. However, you've just replaced the original string, so `google.com` is not *clickable* now. That's why you only get your last link as a result.

---

There are a couple of things you may also want to correct in your code:

1. The regex `#<pre[\s\S]*</pre>#U` is better constructed as `#<pre.*</pre>#Us`. The class `[\s\S]*` is normally used in JavaScript, where there is no `s` flag to allow dots matching newlines.
2. I don't get why you're using that pattern to match URLs. I think you could simply use `https?://\S+`. I'll also link you to some alternatives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161738/5290909).
3. You're using 2 `preg_match_all()` calls and 1 `str_replace()` call for the same text, where you could wrap it up in 1 `preg_replace()`.

**Code**

```
$postbits = "
<pre>
http://www.google.com

http://w...content-available-to-author-only...o.com

http://www.microsoft.com/ <-- only this one clickable
</pre>";


$regex = '#\G((?:(?!\A)|.*<pre)(?:(?!</pre>).)*)(https?://\S+?)#isU';
$repl = '\1<a href="\2" target="_blank">\2</a>';

$postbits = preg_replace( $regex, $repl, $postbits);
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/B62lh1)</kbd>

**Regex**

- `\G` Always from the first matching position in the subject.
- Group 1

  - `(?:(?!\A)|.*<pre)` Matches the first `<pre` tag from the beggining of the string, or allows to get the *next* `<pre` tag if no more URLs found in this tag.
  - `(?:(?!</pre>).)*)` Consumes any chars inside a `<pre>` tag.
- Group 2

  - `(https?://\S+?)` Matches 1 URL.

[image: Regular expression visualization]